# How to check Variant is Unassigned with varByRef flag set?

Tags: delphi

It is recommended to use `VarIsClear` to check is Variant is Null, Empty or Unassigned. But I found function can return False while variable `Unassigned` in debugger if varByRef flag is set. `VarIsClear` checking

```
function VarIsClear(const V: Variant): Boolean;
var
  LHandler: TCustomVariantType;
  LVarData: TVarData;
begin
  LVarData := FindVarData(V)^;
  with LVarData do
    if VType < CFirstUserType then
      Result := (VType = varEmpty) or
                (((VType = varDispatch) or (VType = varUnknown)) and
                  (VDispatch = nil))
    else if FindCustomVariantType(VType, LHandler) then
      Result := LHandler.IsClear(LVarData)
    else
      Result := False;
end;
```

and VType in my case is 16384 ($4000 = varByRef).
How to check is it Null, Empty or Unassigned properly?

Comment: try to make your function to verify this conditions

Comment: Delphi XE2. Code is part of Devart SDAC and Variant param created as indirect as possible during database update. I wonder why Delphi debugger able to calculate that value is Unassigned while own Delphi function not. FindCustomVariantType in VarIsClear returns False.

Comment: How did you get a Variant with such a type value? [MSDN says that type combination isn't valid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa908601.aspx), so behavior of certain functions will naturally be unpredictable. The copy of `VarIsClear` isn't what's relevant here; please post *your* code.

Comment: Code is http://www.devart.com/sdac/ and it is huge. Variant value is param generated to update fields. I'm trying to understand why it happens and my only guess that params reused and if assigned value is Null then happens `Value := Unassigned'. Probably during that byRefFlag can be set from previous iteration?

Comment: You're asking people to look through an entire data-access library to find your problem. Can't you post a half-dozen lines that demonstrate it? "I wrote code *X*, and I expected result *Y*, but I got result *Z* instead." Fill in *X*, *Y*, and *Z*.

Comment: I do not asking to analyze huge project, it is almost impossible for now to find how exactly variant Value receives byRef flag but have Unassigned value in debugger to show as small example. I was expecting to find how exactly Delphi debugger can find value is `Unassigned` while variant functions can't or maybe there is yet another function that able to find it. Even if I can't solve this riddle I marked as answer since there is no solutions available except VarIsEmpty (which still not works with that issue).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

- Check for unassigned with `VarIsEmpty`.
- Check for an undefined value with `VarIsClear`.
- Check for a null value with `VarIsNull`.

So it seems that you need `VarIsEmpty` since you wish to check for an unassigned variant.

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc237865.aspx) your variant type of `VT_EMPTY | VT_BYREF` is invalid. This is explicitly called out in this text:

> The VT_EMPTY and VT_NULL values MUST NOT be specified with the VT_BYREF bit flag.

So this means that your variant is invalid and it is not reasonable to expect anything of the RTL functions when they are presented with invalid input.

I suspect you'll need to either fix the code that serves up this invalid variant, or work around the broken code.

Comment: It was `(Value = Variants.Null) or (VarIsNull(Value)) or (VarIsEmpty(Value))` check. But it was unable to catch this strange case. After check by data type there suppose to be string and AnsiString(Value) cast. By searching I found that VarIsClear able to do the same, but still I have issue.

Comment: VarIsEmpty tests for unassigned

Comment: VarIsEmpty unable to find this case of Unassigned due to `Result := FindVarData(V)^.VType = varEmpty;` where VType = 16384 while varEmpty = 0.

Comment: The obvious conclusion is that variant is not unassigned.

Comment: Except Delphi debugger shows value as `Unassigned`. Anyway I marked as answer since it should be proper answer even if not helps with that strange issue.

Comment: In what way does it not help? The variant is invalid. Not much more to say. The docs could not be clearer. Why do you believe the delphi debugger over the docs?

Comment: It seems it is really invalid (have byRef flag but can't retrieve data by reference, can't find so far why and how it happens, too much indirect code between). Only difference is Delphi debugger shows variable as `Unassigned` while variant functions can't find it is Unassigned.

Comment: @user Since the value is invalid, you can't infer anything from what the debugger says about it. You know that it is invalid. That's the end of story. What the debugger says is of no import. It means nothing.

Comment: I think it's caused by code:  FData := Unassigned;
  TVarData(FData).VType := varByRef;
    TVarData(FData).VPointer := Value; where Value is object.
But I'm not sure how to do it properly.

Comment: Well that code is bogus. Only someone with more knowledge of that code could know how to do it right.

Comment: Isn't that should be like in FPC: TVarData(FData).VType := varByRef or varVariant;

Comment: It should be or'd with something for sure